# Why isn't this transition property working with css?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have simple html doc with a small amount of css. The transform works but not the transition I have tried numerous things and its looks like an exact copy of a tutorial I'm watching, is there something wrong with the syntax that I keep missing or is there something else that's causing it not to work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>transition Learning</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            #testItem{
                background-color: blue;
                width: 80px;
                height: 80px;
                margin: 300px auto;
                transition: transform 600ms ease-in-out;
                transform: translate(200px,200px) rotate(45deg);
            }


        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="testItem"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't have anything transitioning? (Click on the box)

```js
document.getElementById("testItem").onclick = function () {
  this.classList.toggle('transition');
}
```

```css
#testItem.transition {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#testItem{
                background-color: blue;
                width: 80px;
                height: 80px;
                margin: 300px auto;
                transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
                transform: translate(0,0) rotate(45deg);
            }
```

```html
<div id="testItem"></div>
```